# How to compose react-textarea-autosize with react-mentions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mixins, composition, reusability

It's now clear to me that mixins and inheritance are generally considered *bad* and composition is the way to go, this from:

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html

---

Now, what to do when you find two components that specialize in different things and you want a component that is the result of both behaviors mixed? For instance, I want a textarea that both grows automatically when text goes beyond initial rows, and allow mentions inside (aka. mix `react-mentions` with `react-textarea-autosize`)

- How am I supposed to compose both in a way that works?
- Am I supposed to code a brand new component copying/merging the inner code from both components?
- What's the ReactJs way to compose in such scenarios?

Comment: I was wondering whether higher order components might be useful here, but I don't have any concrete ideas.

Comment: @EricWalker there must be a way in which mixins+inheritance is not so bad. I mean, we're in OO for a reason :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across the same issue. With react-mention you don't have to use the react-text-autosize as you can achieve the same behavior with css which can auto grow the textarea generated. Consider following example

```
<MentionsInput
   value={content}
   placeholder="Add a comment"
   onChange={this.onChange}
   className="mentionWrapper">
        <Mention
          trigger="@"
          data={users}
          className="mentionedFriend"
          displayTransform={(id, display) => `@${display}`}
        />
</MentionsInput>
```

For this i've used the following styles

```
.mentionWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #a9b5c4;
 }
 .mentionWrapper .mentionWrapper__control {
   border-radius: 25px;
   border: 1px solid #3a546f;
   min-height: 45px;
  }

 .mentionWrapper .mentionWrapper__control .mentionWrapper__highlighter {
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
 }

 .mentionWrapper .mentionWrapper__control .mentionWrapper__input {
  padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: #7288a3;
  border-color: #3a546f;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.mentionWrapper .mentionWrapper__control .mentionWrapper__input::placeholder {
  color: #7288a3;
 }

.mentionWrapper__suggestions {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) !important;
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 border-radius: 0.8rem;
 }

.mentionWrapper__suggestions .mentionWrapper__suggestions__list {
  font-size: 14px;
 }

.mentionWrapper
.mentionWrapper__suggestions
.mentionWrapper__suggestions__item--focused {
 color: #ffffff;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #3a546f;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.mentionedFriend {
  color: #7288a3;
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

Key point here is that i've applied a min-height of 45px to "control" div which is append by react-mention package. By doing so you will get the attached result.
[image]

Comment: I will accept this as answer, but you can't either resize the input with your mouse in the regular way.

Comment: In the css (.mentionWrapper .mentionWrapper__control .mentionWrapper__input) resize property is set to none, remove it and it will allow the user to resize. You can modify the css to your needs. But resizing is not recommended as we already have auto resize. In my opinion both together won't give an intuitive experience to user.

Comment: @FakhirShad having the `resize: vertical !important;` property does allow the user to resize, but the border doesn't move along...

Do you perhaps have a solution for that issue?

Comment: @FakhirShad, Thanks bro, you save me after hours of research!